# GTM and GA tracking on multiple website platforms

Tags: .net, angularjs, google-tag-manager, tracking, angulartics

I have an e-commerce website built in AngularJS (1.x). I've added GTM and GA support using Angulartics. In order to use Angulartics we have a JSON file which has to be imported into the GTM account.
I have a customer who wishes to use their existing GTM tracking code (the one on their main website). The visitor would click on a link on their main website which would take them to the webshop (hosted on a different domain). Now the problem is that their existing site was built using .Net
They say they cannot import the Angulartics settings into GTM because that would break the tracking on the .Net site.
I'm no GTM expert so I'm not sure what to do...
Does anyone have experience with such a setup? Is there a way to work around this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the JSON import, you can set the file to merge with the existing tags, if you are afraid it would override existing tags/triggers/vars. Personally, I prefer straight imports, but being careful I don't mess anything up (GTM tells you which settings you might override when you import).

What is important in the end is to modify Angulartics triggers to match the other domain only. That way, you won't influence their existing .NET setup and you will have your tracking on the e-comm site only. To add an additional layer of checks, import your Angular GTM stuff into a new WorkSpace (GTM will ask you during the import about it), go into a Preview mode (GTM's debug tool) and test the main site if it gets screwed up.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Igor! I'll give it a try.

Comment: If this works, then can I leave the Angular GTM stuff in a separate WorkSpace? Or do I have to merge them at some point?

Comment: you will have to merge them. this will happen at the point when you publish the workspace you made. eventually, only the "default" workspace remains.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!